# How to orderBy with Firebase and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data from Firebase Realtime Database with Javascript and order it by child's value.

I get the data, and limiting it works, but the order does not change.

Here is what I've tried:

`var ref = database.ref('users').orderByChild('score').limitToLast(10);`

Then I made score key with ".indexOn": "score" on firebase. Then I tried the following.

`var ref = database.ref('users').orderByKey().limitToLast(10);`[enter image description here][1]

I don't understand where I'm going wrong. I would really appreciate help!

Picture of firebase included!

[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV4mI.png)

Comment: Can your edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show how you execute the query, how you then process the data, and what is wrong about it? Showing the problem with `console.log` is preferred, as that makes it easiest for us to look at the same output.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had data in wrong format in firebase.

I had saved the score information as string so that's why orderBy did not give the wanted results.

After I changed the data in firebase the query worked just fine!